# How to push each Excel row to a different html file

Tags: html, excel

I've created an Excel file with 570 rows and I need to export each row to a different .html file.
I've already created the 570 .html files (1.html,2.html....570.html) and they are empty so how can I fill each one with a different ordered row of my Excel file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Note that I haven't tested this as I don't own Excel or any Microsoft products. I've adapted the code from [here](http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=436) in order to work as you asked. I couldn't automate this without using VBA, which *should* come with every copy of Excel. It's basically used to quickly automate macro sequences.

```
Public Sub GenerateHTML(ByVal sTitle As String)

Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim lRow As Long
Dim iColCount As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim sFileName As String
sFileName = "Your-Title-Here" ' Be sure to change this to a title. '

iColCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
For lRow = 1 To 570
    iFileNum = FreeFile
    Open sFileName + "-row" + lRow + ".html" For Output As iFileNum
    Print #iFileNum, "<HTML>"
    Print #iFileNum, "<TITLE>" + sTitle + " Row: " + CStr(lRow) + "</TITLE>"
    Print #iFileNum, "<BODY>"
    Print #iFileNum, "<TABLE BORDER=1>"
    Print #iFileNum, "<TR>"
    For iCol = 1 To iColCount
        Print #iFileNum, "<TD>"
        Print #iFileNum, CStr(Cells(lRow, iCol).Value)
        Print #iFileNum, "</TD>"
    Next iCol
    Print #iFileNum, "</TR>"
    Print #iFileNum, "</TABLE>"
    Print #iFileNum, "</BODY>"
    Print #iFileNum, "</HTML>"
    Close iFileNum
Next lRow
Close iFileNum
End Sub
```